# How to perfrom an aggregate query with condicional filter in django

Tags: python, django, aggregate, django-queryset, annotate

I have this data on the model:

```
[
  {"Field": "value1", "Flag": true},
  {"Field": "value2", "Flag": false},
  {"Field": "value1", "Flag": true},
  {"Field": "value2", "Flag": true},
  {"Field": "value1", "Flag": false},
  {"Field": "value2", "Flag": false},
  {"Field": "value1", "Flag": false}
]
```

I try to aggregate the data with this query when the flag is True:

```
model.objects.values('Field').order_by('Field').annotate(total=Count('Field'), Flag_field=Count('Flag', filter=Q(Flag=True)))
```

And I expect this output in the result of the query:

```
[
   {"Field": "value1", "total": 4, "Flag": 2},
   {"Field": "value2", "total": 3, "Flag": 1}
]
```

try with conditional  aggregation but display this error:

SQLDecodeError

Comment: What Django version do you use? Note that usually you can not annotate with the *same* name as the original field.

Comment: the version of Django is  2.2.1, yes is true but in the real query not use the same name this is an example!

Comment: What if you use `flags=Sum('Flag')` instead?

Comment: Ummm I try with Sum but the flag field is a booblean fiield, Sum is for integer or float field I think!, Now I try with Sum and have the same error!

Comment: no `True` and `False` are just aliasses for `1` and `0`.

Comment: Same error with Sum, meaby other sintax error?

Comment: can you show what query is generated with `print(qs.query)` (with `qs` the queryset)?

Comment: this is the raw query: SELECT "model"."Field", COUNT("model"."field") AS "total", SUM(CASE WHEN "model"."flag" = True THEN "model"."flag" ELSE NULL END) AS "bot2" FROM "model" GROUP BY "model"."field" ORDER BY "model"."field" ASC

Comment: In the SQL output you posted, sometimes "Field" has an uppercase "F", sometimes it has a lowercase "f". That seems odd.

Comment: `True` and `False` are not always aliases for `1` and `0`. In MySQL they are, in Postgres they are not.